# Unit testing React Saga watchers and workers

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, react-redux, redux-saga

I want to do the unit testing for the following watchers and workers using mocha and chai. Can someone help here?

I did write some unit test case but its not working as expected

***example***

```
import { expect } from "chai";
import { take, call } from "redux-saga/effects";

import * as actions from "client/actions";
import { watchGetFavorites } from "client/sagas/watchers/favorite-watcher";
import { fetchFavorites } from "client/sagas/workers/favorite-worker";

describe("favorite-watcher saga", () => {
  const generator = watchGetFavorites();
  it("it should execute watchGetFavorites", () => {
    expect(generator.next().value).to.deep.equal(take(actions.GET_FAVORITES));
  });
  it("it should execute watchGetFavorites api", () => {
    const data = {
      "loadAction": {
        type: actions.GET_FAVORITES,
        "payload": {
          "userId": "id"
        }
      }
    };
    const apiCall = generator.next(data);
    expect(apiCall).to.deep.equal(call(fetchFavorites, data));
  });
});
```

The 1st test case is passing but however the second one is failing and I also want to know how can I test the entire watchers so that it will also cover the worker code.

**RootSaga**

```
import {fork} from "redux-saga/effects";
import * as favoriteWatcher from "./watchers/favorite-watcher";

export default function *rootSaga() {
  yield [
    fork(favoriteWatcher.watchGetFavorites)
  ];
}
```

***Watcher***

```
import {take, call, takeEvery} from "redux-saga/effects";
import * as actions from "../../actions/index";
import * as workers from "../workers/favorite-worker";

export function* watchGetFavorites() {
  const loadAction = yield take(actions.GET_FAVORITES);
  yield call(workers.fetchFavorites, loadAction.payload);
}

export function* watchDeleteFavorites() {
  yield takeEvery(actions.DELETE_FAVORITE, function*(loadAction) {
    yield call(workers.deleteFavorites, loadAction.payload);
  });
}
```

***Worker***

```
export function* fetchFavorites(payload) {// eslint-disable-line
  try {
    const response = yield call(fetchForJson, `${config.API.favoritesListURL}/${payload.userId}`); //api call
    yield put({//dispatch
      type: actions.GET_FAVORITES_SUCCESS,
      result: response.result,
      fetching: false
    });
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({
      type: actions.GET_FAVORITES_ERROR,
      result: error,
      fetching: false
    });
  }
}

export function* deleteFavorites(payload) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(deleteJson, `${config.API.deleteFavoriteURL}/${payload.userId}`, payload); //api call
    yield put({//dispatch
      type: actions.DELETE_FAVORITE_SUCCESS,
      result: response.result,
      fetching: false
    });
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({
      type: actions.DELETE_FAVORITE_ERROR,
      result: error,
      fetching: false
    });
  }
}
```

Any help really appriciated.

Comment: shouldn't use be using the done arg  for the describe function in mocha, as . you would with other async tests?  Secondly, you should likely be testing each saga function calls the correct series of instructions - takes x, calls y, puts z.  getting into testing sagas myself, so I'll come back by here again.